# How do I change root element name while keeping contents using XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML document:

```xml
<data>
    <elmt1>Element 1</elmt1>
    <elmnt2>Element 2</elmnt2>
    <elmnt3>Element 3</elmnt3>
</data>
```

I need to deserialize to an object that serializes to a different root name with everything else remaining the same.

For example:

```xml
<dataNew>
    <elmt1>Element 1</elmt1>
    <elmnt2>Element 2</elmnt2>
    <elmnt3>Element 3</elmnt3>
</dataNew>
```

When serializing, we can always apply `XmlRootAttribute` to serialize to a different root name but I am not sure how to deserialize to a different `XmlRootAttribute`. It keeps failing `error in document (1,2)` pointing to the root attribute.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 25):

If it's only the root name you want to change you can specify the root attribute when declaring the XmlSerializer.

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data), new XmlRootAttribute("dataNew"));
```

Answer (score 17):

XmlRootAttribute was supposed to work

```
[XmlRoot("dataNew")]
public class MyData()
{
    [XmlElement("elmt1")]
    public string myElement1{get;set;}

    [XmlElement("elmnt2")]
    public string myElement2{get;set;}

    [XmlElement("elmtn3")]
    public string myElement3{get;set;}

}
```

EDIT: Completed the XML

Answer (score 6):

Did you try using the [XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx) class?

Comment: You gotta just love all these goodies you find in the framework by surfing this site.

Answer (score 4):

a sample of using XmlAttributeOverrides.  If you vote up give one to [hjb417](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456620/xmlserializer-deserialize-question/1456693#1456693) as well

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead("XmlFile1.xml"))
        using (var fs2 = File.OpenRead("XmlFile2.xml"))
        {
            var xSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
            var obj = xSer.Deserialize(fs);
        //
            var xattribs = new XmlAttributes();
            var xroot = new XmlRootAttribute("dataNew");
            xattribs.XmlRoot = xroot;
            var xoverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
            xoverrides.Add(typeof(data), xattribs);
            var xSer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data), xoverrides);
            var obj2 = xSer2.Deserialize(fs2);
        }
    }
}

public class data
{
    public string elmt1 { get; set; }
    public string elmnt2 { get; set; }
    public string elmnt3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew but my challenge is to deserialize <data> to dataNew object. So, in your code the XML file will be the same but the serialization logic needs to perform something like below

var xSer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(dataNew));            
var obj2 = xSer2.Deserialize(fs1);

Comment: In that case you would replace the XmlRootAttribute("dataNew") with "data" and the typeof(data) would be typeof(dataNew)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExtendedXmlSerializer](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer). This serializer support change root element name and property name. 
If you have class like this:

```
[XmlRoot("dataNew")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("elmt1")]
    public string Element1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("elmnt2")]
    public string Element2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("elmtn3")]
    public string Element3 { get; set; }
}
```

You can serialize it:

```
ExtendedXmlSerializer serializer = new ExtendedXmlSerializer();
var obj = new Data
    {
        Element1 = "A",
        Element2 = "B",
        Element3 = "C",
    };
var xml = serializer.Serialize(obj);
```

Your xml will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataNew type="Models.Example">
    <elmt1>A</elmt1>
    <elmnt2>B</elmnt2>
    <elmtn3>C</elmtn3>
</dataNew>
```

ExtendedXmlSerializer has many other useful features:

- Deserialization xml from standard XMLSerializer
- Serialization class with property interface
- Serialization circular reference and reference Id
- Deserialization of old version of xml
- Property encryption
- Custom serializer

ExtendedXmlSerializer supports .net 4.5 and .net Core. You can integrate it with WebApi and AspCore.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to implement [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) and change the root element in [GetObjectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata.aspx)().