# Why getting error in XML Deserialization?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I'm trying to deserialize XML response received from a webservice. But here I'm getting error.

Here is the XML response that I receive from the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CreateTxResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ResponseCode xmlns="http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/">00000000</ResponseCode>
<ResponseString xmlns="http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/">Successful</ResponseString>
<TxIdentifier xmlns="http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/">MP61313211</TxIdentifier>
<ProcessingDateEST xmlns="http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/">08112017151515</ProcessingDateEST>
<Reserved1 xmlns="http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/">MP61313211|MP61313211|1000|USD|1000|USD|VN|001|Vietnam||D||Dmy||Kar||Nadrazni 2||Prague||CZ|110 00|00420775045652|Galina||Gavrilova|</Reserved1>
<Reserved2 xmlns="http://www.vietcombank.com.vn/">0 - Signature verification successful!</Reserved2>
</CreateTxResponse>
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 41).
```

Inner Exception:

```
<CreateTxResponse xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

Stack trace:

```
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)

  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)

  at secure_service.PSVietcombank.Deserialize[T](XmlDocument response) in C:\....secure_service\PSVietcombank.cs:line 36
```

Here is my code for Deserialization:

```
 public static T Deserialize<T>(XmlDocument response)
 {
     try
     {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(response.OuterXml);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)xs.Deserialize(sr); //hitting error in this line
      }
     catch (Exception)
     { }
     return default(T);
 }
```

I would appreciate any suggestion or help on the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) What is the type `T` to which you are trying to deserialize?  2) What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, full error message, traceback and inner exception?  Often the inner exception will have more details.  3)  Probably the error is as explained in the exception message: your type `T` isn't named `CreateTxResponse` and doesn't override the [root element name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456620).

Comment: don't swallow your exception, log it.

Comment: Show how `CreateTxResponse` looks like.

Comment: I sure hope the information is debug information, and not actual clientele information.

Comment: @dbc type T is a C# Class of PSVietcombank and regarding the error I've updated the question with the error details.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I don't have a class for CreateTXResponse this is going to receive from the client service and then deserialize, read and store into db.

Comment: The only way I found to solve issue in the past is to skip first line of xml like this :             StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine();
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(reader);

Comment: Unless you actually show us a (possibly simplified) version of  `PSVietcombank` that reproduces the problem -- i.e. a [mcve] -- we can only guess the problem.  My guess is that you need to add `[XmlRoot("CreateTxResponse")]` to `PSVietcombank` as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456620).

Comment: You might consider just getting what you need using XPath and SelectNodes  / SelectSingleNode it's a more direct and debugable approach.